# Issue with file in formidable.Files. Throws an error ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, parsing, formidable

Im doing W3 schools tutorial. I wanted do change path of chosen file. To be honest, I'm a little surprised that code straight from w3 doesn't work. Maybe in the meantime something has changed in syntax?

I tried changing 'filepath' to 'path'. Wanted to make `files.filetoupload.filepath` in `${here}`, but it gave me undefined. Don't know what to do...

I want to change `dir` of a file, but `files.filetoupload.filepath` is returning undefined instead of string.

```
Error code is: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'

throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(propName, ['string', 'Buffer', 'URL'], path);

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "oldPath" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL.
```

```
Node version:Node.js v18.12.1.
Formidable version:8.19.2.
```

```
var http = require('http');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/fileupload') {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
      var oldpath = files.filetoupload.filepath;
      var newpath = 'C:/Users/Your Name/' + files.filetoupload.originalFilename;
      fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.write('File uploaded and moved!');
        res.end();
      });
 });
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
    res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
    res.write('<input type="submit">');
    res.write('</form>');
    return res.end();
  }
}).listen(8080);
```

Please let me know, what is wrong here.

Comment: Did you change the newpath variable according to your own username?

Comment: Yes. used "C:/Users/thinkpad/". But I don't think, that this is the problem.

Comment: how do you have Formidable version:8.19.2. the latest is 3.5.0 ? Also what happens if you console.log(files.filetoupload) ?

Comment: I am also having the same issue... can someone help please

Comment: @WalleCyril `files.filetoupload` will be an array of one `PersistentFIle`. I tried `files.filetoupload[0].filepath` still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

it means something wrong with this line `var oldpath = files.filetoupload.filepath;`

and I would recommend you take a look at the breakdown details of **files**, **files.filetoupload** to see what elements inside them. you can add `console.log(files);` below your **var oldpath**, like this

```
var oldpath = files.filetoupload.filepath;
console.log(files);
```

mine looks like below
[image]

based on above you would know **filetoupload** is a list/array, so the correct way to parse it is
`var oldpath = files.filetoupload[0].filepath;`

and please also change your newpath variable as well
`var newpath = '/Replace/With/Your/Own/' + files.filetoupload[0].originalFilename;`

basically, the idea is that you have to debug by figuring our your own **files** format, and print it out to check what is the best way to parse its element out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of renaming with fs.rename use the option options.filename like so

```
var options = {
    filename: function (name, ext, part, form) {
        const { originalFilename, mimetype} = part;
        retrun 'C:/Users/thinkpad/' + originalFilename;
    }
}
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm(options );
```

Comment: since originalFilename is technically user input , you should also remove special characters from it